# Midvatten: how to set the ground level elevation from which to start the stratigraphy?

Tags: midvatten

I have the stratigraphy of some points and the elevation of the ground level.
I would like to set the altitude of the ground level to ensure that the 'zero' of the stratigraphy starts from that altitude.
For example
p1: elevation 6 m amsl; sand top 0 sand bot 2, silt top 2 silt bot 4
p2: elevation -1m amsl; sand top 0, sand bot 3, silt top 3 sitl bot 5

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Have a look at the database tables here https://github.com/jkall/qgis-midvatten-plugin/wiki/database-tables
Table "obs_points" field "h_gs"